# What interface does a SD Card use?

Tags: sd-card

What interface does a SD Card use? I looked at the Wikipedia article and they mention SDIO. However this seems to be just for non data transfer. Is the interface usb like? Completely usb? If it is not usb, can windows be installed and booted off it (The aleutia computer (just randomly browsing web) supports booting xp off a compact flash card)?

Comment: CF is essentially repackaged IDE (PATA). I believe you can use use a passive adapter. SD is completely different and not directly adaptable to any standard internal interfaces. You *might* be able to boot off a SD card with a card reader, but most come up as USB mass storage - not all operating systems and/or computers will support booting from that, especially not out of the box. I believe Linux can, and maybe Windows with some hacking. We have a couple of questions concerning booting Windows from a flash drive.

Answer (score 0):

Whether Windows can be booted from SD card depends on whether the computer BIOS or UEFI supports booting from SD. The details of the interface are unimportant (it includes [SPI](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Serial_Peripheral_Interface_Bus)).